# Pass function parameters for json fill drop down

Tags: ajax, json

How would pass the parameter into "foodName" from the function that sends the url and id? i.e. could you do something like the function: 
    call('/url/to/foodlist', "foodList", "food"); 
and replace 
    var input = item.food;?

Below is working code but would like a more general function then having to use part of name in the function (replace foodName so that it isn't in this function)

```
function call(url, id){
var string = '';
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: url,
success: function (item)
if (item != '') {
  var input = item.foodName;
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  string += = '<option value=' + input[i].name + '">' + input[i].name + '</option>';
  }
$('#' + id). append(string);
}
```

});

call('/url/to/foodlist', "foodList");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function call(url, id, paramName){
var string = '';
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: url,
success: function (item)
if (item != '') {
  var input = item[paramName]; // you can access to the properties using braces
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  string += = '<option value=' + input[i].name + '">' + input[i].name + '</option>';
  }
$('#' + id). append(string);
}
```